# How to use pythontex.py from TeXnicCenter?

Tags: compiling, texniccenter, python, pythontex

I have installed Windows 7, MiKTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter 2.02 stable and Python 3.4.1 (distribution pyzo2015a). I use

> latex pythontex.ins

form `cmd` to install the package [`pythontex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex):

[image].

It seems to me that no files have been created in MiKTeX. Hence I have recopied manually the files to the appropriate directories as [README](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/README).

My `pythontex.bat` (in `C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`) contains

> @echo off
>   "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py" 
>   %*

My PATH contains

> C:\pyzo2015a;C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\windows\system32

I used the following commands in the `cmd`:

[image]

From the [quickstart](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf) of this package:

"Compiling a document that uses pythontex involves three steps: run LATEX, run pythontex.py, and finally run LATEX again".

I tried:
[image]

And the .pdf file obtained from the tex file (after several latex compilation) looks like this: ??

1) I am not able to process the second step. How do I activate pythontex.py on a `.tex` file from TeXnicCenter? My feeling is that my system does not recognise `pythontex.py`: there is a problem in my installation of `pythontex`.

2) Is it possible to make automatic this task with TeXnicCenter (by using a postprocessor?)? I use

> C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe

in my profile.

Comment: Using a postprocessor would work. It should add only a tiny amount of overhead compared to creating a special profile or keyboard shortcut for running pythontex, and then manually running pythontex as needed. If you used the pythontex installation script, there should be a batch file pythontex.bat under C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin that you can use to run pythontex. Otherwise, you could run pythontex.py directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I should have clarified that the installation script I meant was `pythontex_install.py`, which can be used after generating `pythontex.sty` to move files automatically. At this point, running `pdflatex test.tex`, `pythontex test.tex`, and finally `pdflatex test.tex` should work. If `pythontex` is giving any error messages, please add those to your question. Also, knowing what is in `test.tex` might help.

Comment: It has been more than 10 years since I used TeXnicenter.  You need to open Help-Search-Contents-Configuration-ManualConfiguration.  You will  read about how to use the different tabs.  Now set your LaTeX compiler choice on the first tab, the python compiler in the preprocessing tab, and choose the viewer on the fourth tab if desired.  When I was using TeXnicenter with students, we ran Python, C+, Java, MySQL, sed, awk, perl, asmptote, and R either as pre-  and/or post-processors with settings in the build menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was also groping for a solution to *"How to run PythonTeX within my local computer"* while [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com) did it (very slowly and intermittently, but) correctly and seamlessly on the cloud.

This is what I could figure out for myself, and hope should work for anyone too:

1. If `pythontex` is installed (as is evident from the options displayed when you type `MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py`), then just locate the pythontex code file in your project.  In my case it was `test.pytxcode`, while my main TeX file was `test.tex` (both in the same directory).
2. On my console, I just ran the command :

   ```
   pythontex test.pytxcode
   ```

   and that did it all !
   This is the output I got--

   ```
   This is PythonTeX 0.16
   --------------------------------------------------
   PythonTeX:  local_test - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
   ```
3. As in the guidelines, compile with [pdf]LaTeX before and after the python run.
4. ...and *Voila* !